Game won't end when entity hits player
I'm learning game development, more specifically coding. I'm starting on Scratch as I'm still in High School and don't have much time. I'm trying to make it so the game ends when the Zombie touches the player. I tried this but it isn't working. Does anyone know what I should do to fix it?


I figured out you have to put "When I start as a clone" Instead of "When Flag Clicked"
